# MySQL Query ordered by Date

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a MySQL query, ordered sequentially by date. How would I go about doing this? Is there a way? Trying to make a web app where the most recent date is the field that sorts the other two fields.

Comment: `SELECT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY date`?

Comment: Post the code of an example query that you are working on ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select fields from tables order by dateField
```

or

`select fields from tables order by dateField desc` depending on your preferred order